# Load GeoJSON file in OpenLayers 3?

Tags: openlayers

Before, to load my .geojson, I had a php file who generated the code :

```
var vector_limite_comm_white = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.GeoJSON({
        url: 'geojson1.php',
        defaultProjection :'EPSG:4326', projection: 'EPSG:3857'
    }), 
    name: 'NAME 1',
    style: style_white()
})
```

After, I tried to **directly** load my **geojson file**, so I wrote :

```
var vector_name1    = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector ({
        url: 'data/json/file1.geojson',
        defaultProjection :'EPSG:4323', projection: 'EPSG:3857'

    }),
    name: 'NAME 1',
    style: style_white()
})
```

In firebug, at onload event, I saw my geojson file was loaded correctly but, it doesn't appear in my map. So I tried an other method like that :

```
var test = 'data/json/file1.geojson';
var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
    features: (new ol.format.GeoJSON()).readFeature(test)
}); 
var vector_overlay = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: vectorSource,
    style: new ol.style.Style(style_white()
});
```

It's not a good method too.

Do you have some explications?

Comment: need to a live link to debug (jsfiddle etc) but crs needs to be set see http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/geojson.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have a issu with your projection.
Try getting the extent of your json layer :

```
layer.getSource().getExtent();
```

Comment: Where do you write this part of code ?

Comment: use your firebug, get hold of your layer using : map.getLayers().getArray()[x]

Comment: If I test the getSource().getExtent() code, I've, with the code console.log, the result is : [Infinity, Infinity, -Infinity, -Infinity] ...

Answer (score 5):

You gave me a good idea with this code jules and mapperz.

The problem was the not good crs of my Geojson.

So the good code **for a version of OpenLayers < 3.5** is :

`var layer1=new ol.layer.Vector({
   source: new ol.source.GeoJSON ({
           url: 'data/json/mydata.geojson',
           defaultProjection :'EPSG:4326', projection: 'EPSG:3857'
   }),
   name: 'NAME 1',
   style: style_1()
})`

For the version 3.5.0 that's it :

```
var layer1=new ol.layer.Vector({

   source: new ol.source.Vector({

      url: 'data/geojson/mydata.geojson',
      format: new ol.format.GeoJSON({

         defaultDataProjection :'EPSG:4326', 
         projection: 'EPSG:3857'

      })

   }),
   name: 'NAME 1',
   style: style_1()
});
```

Comment: Good to here !!