# GeoJSON features are added to null island when dynamically loaded in Openlayers3

Tags: javascript, openlayers, geojson

I'm trying to add features from a GeoJSON response in openlayers3.
Using the default loading method works great:

```
layer.setSource(new ol.source.Vector({url:url, format:new ol.format.GeoJSON()});
```

But I need error handling, So I use the response from a standard jquery loader like so:

```
var features = new ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeatures(response);
layer.setSource(new ol.source.Vector({features:features}));
```

All the features appear bunched on null island in a sort of a mini-map:
[image]

And a closer look reveals the features:
[image]

edit:Specifying the data/feature projection doesn't work either.

EDIT:
I finally fixed it, Here's the code:

```
var reader = new ol.format.GeoJSON({
    defaultDataProjection:'EPSG:3857',
    Projection:'EPSG:3857'
});
layer.getSource().addFeatures(reader.readFeatures(res,{
    dataProjection:'EPSG:4326',
    featureProjection:'EPSG:3857'
}));
```

What an absolute nightmare that was.

Comment: You say "Specifying the data/feature projection doesn't work either.", but did you specify the correct projection? This is probably a WGS84 vs Google Mercator problem ;)

Comment: The projection is EPSG:4326 WGS84. I verified it with QGIS, Exported it again just in case, Added a crs member to the GeoJSON response and defined both data and feature projection as EPSG:4326. It didn't work.

Comment: How did you specify the projection in OL? Try http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/148593/51035 . Your map is probably in 3857 while your GeoJSON is 4326.

Comment: The extent I'm getting is [ -171.791111, -18.347975, 145.543137, 71.357764 ]. I changed the projection to EPSG:3857 and nothing really changed.

Comment: Thank you very much. Messing with OL 4 is also a nightmare, the docs have NO examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it by playing with the projection options:

```
var reader = new ol.format.GeoJSON({
defaultDataProjection:'EPSG:3857',
Projection:'EPSG:3857'
});
layer.getSource().addFeatures(reader.readFeatures(res,{
    dataProjection:'EPSG:4326',
    featureProjection:'EPSG:3857'
}));
```